# How to use x:Bind with different data type than data template

Tags: xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp, prism

I'm working on a view (called 'Familify') which shows users a list of assets, and allows them to delete an asset from the list. The assets are stored in an `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel, so the command to delete simply takes the asset object and removes it from collection. I'm having issues getting the 'delete' functionality working. Here is the XAML and codebehind:

**Familify.xaml**

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Assets}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80px" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150px" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60px" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Text="{Binding number}" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="{Binding type}"/>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Text="add binding here"/>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    Text="add binding here"/>
                <Button
                    Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.RemoveAssetCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    Content="&#xE894;"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    Grid.Column="4">
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Familify.xaml.cs**

```
namespace asset_manager.Views
{
    public sealed partial class Familify : UserControl
    {
        FamilifyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        public Familify()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            DataContextChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                ViewModel = DataContext as FamilifyViewModel;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that clicking the button removes the asset from the list. (Just to note, the normal binding showing `number`, `type`, etc. is working correctly.) My thinking so far:

1. Try to use `binding` to access the `RemoveAssetCommand` stored in the View Model for the page. However, I couldn't get ancestral binding to work (i.e. trying to find the data context of an element higher up in the XAML hierarchy didn't work because `findAncestor` isn't a thing in UWP.)
2. `x:Bind` looked like a good solution, because it uses an explicit path to the property. So, if I declared `ViewModel` in my code behind, I could use `x:Bind ViewModel.property`. All well and good. I did just that, and intellisense allowed me to access the ViewModel.RemoveAssetCommand when typing it out.
3. However, this did not work, because I get the error `no DataType defined for DataTemplate`. This makes sense, so I tried two things.
4. `x:DataType="Models:Asset"` (put in the `DataTemplate` tag above) is the model being shown in the data template, so I tried that first. Of course, the command is not declared in the model, it's declared in the View Model, so that didn't work.
5. I instead tried `x:DataType="ViewModels:FamilifyViewModel"`, thinking I could just use `x:Bind` with that. However, I then got an error that it couldn't cast an object of type `Asset` to `FamilifyViewModel`. This makes sense, because the object getting passed to this data template is of the type `Asset`.

This is a pain, because the whole reason I thought `x:Bind` would work is that I could just access the property directly from the ViewModel in the codebehind.

Explicitly stated, 1) is it possible to use `x:Bind` within a data template to access a base level property (in this case, a Prism command) on the `ViewModel`? and 2) is there a better way to go about implementing this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use x:Bind within a data template to access a base level property (in this case, a Prism command) on the ViewModel?

Yes, if you want to access a base level, you can reassign DataContext of button like following:

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Familily, Path=DataContext}"/>
```

The `Family` is the name of `UserControl`.

> is there a better way to go about implementing this functionality?

When you put `commad` in the `ViewModel` and bind the button as above. The the bind item of button will become Family `DataContext`. So you could not invoke delete action directly in the `ViewModel`.

The best practice to implement this functionality is that put the  `RemoveAssetCommand` in the `Asset` class. And use the `ItemsSource` of `ListView` as `Button` `CommandParameter`.

```
<Button 
    Command="{Binding RemoveAssetCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=ItemsSource}"
    Content="&#xE894;"
    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
    Grid.Column="4">
</Button>
```

**Asset.cs**

```
public class Asset
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public ICommand RemoveAssetCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommandHandler<ObservableCollection<Asset>>((item) => this.RemoveAction(item));
        }
    }
    private void RemoveAction(ObservableCollection<Asset> items)
    {
        items.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class FamilifyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Asset> Assets = new ObservableCollection<Asset>();
    public FamilifyViewModel()
    {
        Assets.Add(new Asset { number = "100001", type = "hello" });
        Assets.Add(new Asset { number = "100001", type = "hello" });
        Assets.Add(new Asset { number = "100001", type = "hello" });
        Assets.Add(new Asset { number = "100001", type = "hello" });
    }        
}
```

[image]